# preg_replace for some characters in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How to use preg_replace（） in php to replace comma, space, hyphen to underscore.

```
(i.e) http://test.com/test-one,two three  to http://test.com/test_one_two_three

(i.e) http://test.com/test, new one  to http://test.com/test_new_one
```

I am very weak in reg_exp

Comment: Rather than asking for a solution to be given to you, you should try to become better with regexes.

Comment: What have your tried? What were the results? What were you expecting? Have you tried it in any regex tester outside of PHP?

Comment: Try it out for yourself by using the RegEx Coach for example http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string:

```
$link = 'http://test.com/test-one,two three';
```

#### preg_replace

```
echo preg_replace('/[\s,-]+/', '_', $link);
```

#### str_replace

```
$arr = array(",", " ", "-", "__");
echo str_replace($arr, "_", $link);
```

Comment: Isn't simple `str_replace()` better for that task?

Comment: Questioner want to use `preg_replace`

Comment: I know, but it's good idea to tell him about better way to do it ;) RegExp is not for searching/replacing known strings.

Comment: @ElonThan Added for you ;) Btw, `preg_replace` is good idea for me according to `str_replace` :)

Comment: Why is it good idea in that case?

Comment: Just another point: in this case it works OK, but basically you should take care to put the `-` in a character class always at the end like `[\s,-]` since it has special meaning inside `[]` and describes a character range from...to.

Comment: Nice discussion going on this questoin :)

Comment: `str_replace` a little fast according to `preg_replace` but intervention can be better with a regex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! one more thing i need is. if url is like 'http://test.com/test, new one' then i want only 'http://test.com/test_new_one' as output. Now it shows two underscore for comma and space next to 'test' as 'http://test.com/test__new_one'

Comment: What happens when the url becomes `http://www.some-example.org/`? I don't think the host name should change.

Comment: @Jack I guess his url not contain hyphen. Probably just checking for own site

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```
<?php
    $subject = "http://test.com/test-one,two three";
    echo preg_replace ("/[, -]/" , "_", $subject);
?>
```

Comment: This is correct. The `-` should be the last char in the `[]` to avoid confusing it with a range.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a preview of the functionality I would like to add into PHP:

```
function url_replace($url, $component, callable $callback)
{
    $map = [
        PHP_URL_SCHEME => 2,
        PHP_URL_HOST => 4,
        PHP_URL_PATH => 5,
        PHP_URL_QUERY => 7,
        PHP_URL_FRAGMENT => 9,
    ];

    if (!array_key_exists($component, $map)) {
        return $url;
    }
    $index = $map[$component];

    if (preg_match('~^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?~', $url, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE) && isset($matches[$index])) {
        $tmp = call_user_func($callback, $matches[$index][0]);
        return substr_replace($url, $tmp, $matches[$index][1], strlen($matches[$index][0]));
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Answering your question becomes:

```
$url = 'http://test.com/test-one,two three';
echo url_replace($url, PHP_URL_PATH, function($path) {
    return strtr($path, ', -', '___');
});
```

Result:

```
http://test.com/test_one_two_three
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, there's also `strtr`:

```
strtr('http://test.com/test-one,two three', '-, ', '___');
```

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? It's perfectly fine.